# Cursor for selecting from a View in MySQL always dismiss decimal points in procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view

I have a View which returns two decimal numbers and a Procedure which selects the View using a Cursor, the problem is when the values are retrieved from the FETCH of the Cursor, the decimal points are been removed or it's an Integer.

I've tried in different versions of MySQL and it's the same.

```
CREATE VIEW show_numbers AS SELECT 1.32, 3.01;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE calculate_numbers()
BEGIN 

    DECLARE number_1 DECIMAL DEFAULT 0.0;
    DECLARE number_2 DECIMAL DEFAULT 0.0;

    DECLARE result CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM show_numbers;

    open result;
    FETCH result INTO number_1, number_2;
    close result;

    SELECT number_1, number_2;

END

call calculate_numbers(); -- shows (1, 3) not(1.32, 3.01)
```

see the example [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uGW7fF6bSJW6WCdtR9Za5L/0)

Comment: @RaymondNijland I was just trying to minimize the problem as much as possible, it was in a much bigger procedure.

Comment: *"I was just trying to minimize the problem as much as possible, it was in a much bigger procedure"*  Fair enough i was just checking, then i didn't say anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always define the DECIMAL datatype with precision and scale. You can for example use `DECIMAL(8,2)`.

See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html).

Comment: Topicstarter he means that you need to define `DECLARE number_1 DECIMAL(8,2) DEFAULT 0.0;
    DECLARE number_2 DECIMAL(8,2) DEFAULT 0.0;` instead .. See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uGW7fF6bSJW6WCdtR9Za5L/0)

Comment: @slaakso perfect, Thanks a lot.